# passing value from select_tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to pass selected :ammount value to my controller as :quantity. What i am doing wrong?

```
<%= label(:ammount, "Ammount:") %>
<%= select_tag(:ammount, options_for_select([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])) %>

<%= button_to 'Add to cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product.id, :quantity => :ammount) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use form here to pass the data to controller`s action:

```
<%= form_tag line_items_path(:product_id => product.id) do %>
  <%= label(:ammount, "Ammount:") %>
  <%= select_tag(:ammount, options_for_select([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Add to cart' %>
<% end %>
```

All that you did in your sources is just passing symbol `:ammount` to a controller`s action as a quantity param.

Comment: Thank you for answer! This fixxed my issue! ;)